# Want to Remove Archives from Thunder Bird

Tags: archiving

I have a problem with Thunder Bird.... I want to remove Archives folder from Folders.
All the sent mails are getting archived and getting transferred to archive folder automatically. I am facing lot of problem because of this.Need help on this. Please give me some solution to remove this Archives Folder..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In Thunderbird, use Tools > Account Settings.  Go to Copies & folders for the account in question.  Look at When Sending Messages, Automatically" and make sure that "Place a copy in" is selected, then either "Sent folder on ..." or if Other, make sure it says "Outbox" and not the Archive folder.

Underneath that, uncheck "Keep Message Archives in" completely.

[image: https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2011-09-20-00-41-23-7f844c.png]